# Spring directory structure with interfaces (best practices)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm currently writing my first Spring application (Spring boot + hibernate). I checked the best practices directory structure on their documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html). It makes sense.

**Question 1:**

I have an `interface` (or `Abstract class`) that a few subclasses extend, and so I only need a `@Repository` for the parent class. I've decided to do it this way:

```
com
 +- example
     +- myapplication
         +- Application.java
         |
         +- message
         |   +- AbstractMessage.java
         |   +- IMessageRepository.java
         |   +- MessageRepositoryImpl.java
                +- messageTypeA
                |  +- messageTypeA.java
                |  +- messageTypeAService.java
                +- messageTypeB
                |  +- messageTypeB.java
                |  +- messageTypeBService.java
```

**Question 2:**

Now I have a new `entity` to save called `Group`. So what I could do is add a `Group` directory on the same level as `Message`. However, this `Group` is actually a part of `Message` (like, logically), so it would actually make sense if it was part of the same `message` directory (*the only reason we are saving them as different entities is because it makes more sense to derive analytics that way*). Furthermore I'm even using the same `MessageRepository` to save it (I just added a second method in the interface like so:)

```
public interface MessageRepository {

    void insert(AbstractMessage message);

    void insert(AbstractMessage message, AbstractGroup group);
}
```

Would something like the following be good? Or should *every* `entity` have its own package? Am I overthinking this?

```
com
 +- example
     +- myapplication
         +- Application.java
         |
         +- message
         |   +- AbstractMessage.java
         |   +- IMessageRepository.java
         |   +- MessageRepositoryImpl.java
             |  +- messageTypeA
             |     +- messageTypeA.java
             |     +- messageTypeAService.java
             |  +- messageTypeB
             |     +- messageTypeB.java
             |     +- messageTypeBService.java
             |
             +- group
                +- AbstractGroup.java
                +- GroupTypeX.java // same service as message, just different entity
                +- GroupTypeY.java // same service as message, just different entity
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's more an opinion-based thing, but I'd like to give you a couple suggestions.

First of all, *naming*.
The `I` prefix on interfaces is an "ancient" technique from IBM to recognize them. Please, don't do that, it's reduntant, it doesn't make sense in a fresh environment. What's an `I-MessageRepository`?!
You'll find this kind of naming convention mostly on `Eclipse RCP` projects, or any product by IBM.

Then the implementation name. Don't use the `Impl` suffix, it does not say anything to the person who is reading or editing your code.
Give it a name which says what its purpose or domain scope is.

```
ActiveMQMessageRepository
FileMessageRepository
TcpMessageRepository
```

---

Second, `Repositories`.
Repositories should manage a single type of object, not more than one. Use `Services` to coordinate multiple `Repositories`. This will make it easier for everyone to debug, and it will decouple a lot of code.

---

Third, `packages`.
Try to always have a flat package structure. A flat structure is easier to maintain, easier to look at, easier to understand. Don't create dozens of sub-packages such as

```
- messages
   - services
       MessageService
     - implementations
        ...
   - repositories
       MessageRepository
     - abstract
         AbstractMessageRepository
     - implementations
         TextMessageRepository
   - exceptions
     - runtime
     - checked
         UnsupportedMessageException
```

Horrible and useless. And **you cannot leverage package visibility**.

So keep `messages` and `groups` on separate packages, and give them their own `Repository`.

**Expose interfaces from packages, not concrete implementations.** (when possible)

Comment: thanks :) Those names were made up anyways, I just specified those values here so it could be easier for people to realize it was an interface!

Comment: Though what I don't understand is you say to expose interfaces but also that `repositories` should only manage a single type of object? By single type of object you mean interface right? Not concrete implementation? For example my repository is managing my `Message` interface, and then make a second repository managing my `Group` interface. Not have a `repository` for EVERY concrete implementation.

Comment: @Tiberiu sure, I mean accepting a single kind of interface. This way it will be easier to keep your Repositories and Servicies as small as possible. Less code, less bugs ;)

Comment: @LppEdd Is it a good practice to use the name BaseEntity or AbstractEntity in a class to be inherited?

Comment: @BraianSilva well, it really depends. If every Base/Abstract class on your codebase offers the same kind of basic functionality, the naming could work. Otherwise, it is better to think about another descriptive name

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @LppEdd answer above. Just one question what do you mean when you say

> (the only reason we are saving them as different entities is because it makes more sense to derive analytics that way).

Comment: They're probably measuring workload on those domain models.

Comment: ok, in that case they can use hibernate envers for auditing. If as a future requirement you see that code may need to be broken into microsevices you can break services into separate modules, but if thats not the case i stand by the above response from LppEdd.

Comment: @bornleo What I mean by that is that the messages we receive (that are stored as-is in tables), are their own `entity`. Within this message there's a field `group` that can have multiple values (think map or 2d array). Rather than using `2darray` datatypes in the DB we prefer just to create a separate table and link them by a unique key. So I created a second entity `group` because it now has its own table (even though technically it's a field in the original `message` -- hence package hierarchy question).

Comment: Will/can group entity be queried independent of message, if yes then definitely a separate repository otherwise you can have separate table but still a single repository, make sense?